# HashMap .put() flags incompatible types error

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to place an array of objects and its equivalent id inside a HashMap.

This is my HashMap:

```
private Map<String, Value[]> array_memory = new HashMap<String, Value[]>();
```

This my array of objects:

```
Value[] array = new Value[x];
```

And this is how I'm putting them inside array_memory:

```
return array_memory.put(id, array);
```

However, when I run my program I'm getting this error:

```
error: incompatible types: Value[] cannot be converted to Value
    return array_memory.put(id, array);
                           ^
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. (I would like to apologize if I'm missing something obvious, I've been working on this for hours now and I'm not in my best condition).

Thank you for your time!

Comment: [Nope, runs fine.](https://ideone.com/2NRWtV) Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume this takes place inside a method with a return type of `Value`. The compiler complains about this because `map#put` returns the value being added, leading to this error because a `Value[]` can't be converted to a `Value`.

Answer (score 1):

It look fine with the code snippet you provided.

I think that the variable receiving your returned `array_memory.put(id, array)` is of type `Value` instead of `Value[]`

Answer (score 0):

The put Function returns the second parameter, maybe you get your type missmatch in the return.